# Find old files in HDFS folder

Tags: shell, hdfs

I want to find old files (more than 2 hours for example) in HDFS partition.
"-mmin" is not recognized, have you an another idea ?

My code :

```
hdfs dfs -find /user/TEST/REP -name "*.log.*" -mmin +120
```

Return : find: Unexpected argument: -mmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :

The difference is in minutes.

```
now=$(date +%s)
# Loop in ls result (remove first line like "Found 6 items")
hdfs dfs -ls $PATH_TO_CHECK | grep -v "Found" | while read f; do 
  file_date=$(echo $f | awk '{print $6}')
  file_time=$(echo $f | awk '{print $7}')

  difference=$(( ( $now - $(date -d "$file_date $file_time" +%s) ) / (60) ))

  if [[ "$difference" -gt "$MAX_DURATION" ]]; then
    echo "KO"
  else
    echo "OK"
  fi
```